# Add left and right arrows to scroll slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uislider

Is it possible to add left and right arrows to a jQuery UI Slider in addition to the default scrollbar?

The particular example I am using is this -> http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll

As you can see it comes with the drag slider at the bottom of the content.  However, I would like to add also a left and right arrow when mouse hover over, it will incrementally scroll the scrollbar left and right respectively.

Any insights on this is appreciated!

Comment: yes, it is possible. use the API provided to set the value of the slider.

Comment: I tried it and didn't work...

Comment: in that case, show us what you did, and someone will be able to help you get your code working.

Comment: Here is a fiddle.net code of what I have currently http://jsfiddle.net/j4WY6/11/  You can see that hovering over the left/right link does indeed scroll the "value" of the slider but the content is not moving for some reason.   I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were missing a small detail. The slider widget by itself does not control the position of the content. Its `slide` method takes care of that. When you updated the value of the slider programmatically, this method was not called, because no user interaction occurred.

I refactored your code to make the `slide` no longer be an anon function. i call it from the hover handers:

http://jsfiddle.net/j4WY6/13/

Comment: thank you so much...exactly what I needed...most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this page. This would help you.

http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/scroll_buttons_and_snap_scrolling_examples.html